# Change nav-menu HTML between different screen sizes with java?

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I spent the entire day creating a lovely navigation bar, but the only way I could make it resize enough to fit the a-elements together on a tablet without it starting to stack them, was if I made the nav links stand unlisted, as in, only as:

```
<a href="page1.html" id="temp">Temp</a>
<a href="page2.html" id="temp2">Temperature</a>
```

and then just using inline on them.

So I removed all the li parts from my nav, as it was previously:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html" id="temp">Temp</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" id="temp2">Temperature</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

Unfortunatly, that left my mobile nav in trouble... It does activate on smaller screens with the "press here for menu" button, but since there is no li to display, there is nothing there... some images displayed on the bigger nav-menu is also left floating around rather uselessly on the mobile screen.

So I tried doing this in my index:

```
  <div id="navstor"><a href="navstor.html" ></a></div>
    <div id="navlille"><a href="navlille.html"></a></div>
```

and added this to my script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ( $(window).width() > 641) {
  $("#Navstor").load("navstor"); {
}
else {
  $("#Navlille").load("navlille"); {
}
```

It does not work which I figured. I am very new and almost never use javascript. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove the tags, and you don't need javascript. This is a job for [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

Something like this will let you apply a style between a min and max width, though it is more common to set a few breakpoints with just a min or a max.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
```

Comment: But the style is not the problem, the HTML is. The HTML for the nav has to change between screensizes, since the navbar I created for mobile needs the nav-links to be ul/li to work, and the navbar for bigger screens needs them to NOT be ul/li, and I cant find out how to make my webpage load one menu.html on big screens, and one html.menu on mobile. :(

Comment: No- the html stays - the style changes - Share your styles and I can help you get it working.

Comment: Mobile: https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/RxZJaG

Large devices: https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/xpLzbo

They look better in my editor. Not used to using codepen and such (also, they are not totally perfect yet. I have yet to find out how to solve the problem with the white box in my large menu flying off to space when the height of the screen is lesser than my own laptops!) Still, I quite like them and would like to use them. But the smaller one requires ul to work, and the bigger on only works without ul.

Comment: Thanks for responding and placing your code in the CodePens. I have one based off of your mobile code. I added the large device styles wrapped in a media query so you can get the idea. https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/EoveLd

Comment: Another way to implement this that may be easier for you would be to wrap all of the mobile nav items in one div with a .mobile class and the larger device styles in with another class and then just show/hide those sections using the media query. Hope this helped!

Comment: Goodness, I am utterly speechless, that was so nice of you, thank you. You are my hero JasonB!